What term is used for emotions or feelings such as 'thirst, hunger, fear, jealousy, etc.'
I am writing about the expression of feelings in a Luganda. There is a construction which literally translates to 'X bites me', meaning 'I feel X'. X can be hunger, thirst, fever, sickness, jealousy, etc.
I am familiar with the terms 'stimulus' and 'experiencer' (for instance, in 'jackfruit makes me thirsty' 'jackfruit' is the stimulus and 'me' is the experiencer) but what is the role of X? I don't think it is 'stimulus' as it is not the thing that makes you feel a certain way, but rather the sensation itself.I cannot find the answer in the literature.

experiencer is not very "scientific".  I frankly don't understand your question. x is the subject of the sentence you give there.

"experiencer" is a theta role. I'm looking for a similar thing. I'm leaning towards "experience" but I don't think that's what's used in the literature.
